# How do I let Googlebot crawl content loaded from AJAX but prevent it from indexing the URL hit?

Tags: ajax, seo, googlebot

I have a set of pages on my site wherein I post "main content" on page load and "related content" after page load via an AJAX hit. What I want to do is to ensure Googlebot can get the content loaded via AJAX, and follow the links therein, but not index the request URL.

If I disallow the URL in robots.txt, Googlebot will not crawl the content. If I add a X-Robots-tag "noindex" to it, the whole page will become un-indexed which is not what I want. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask the crawler to wait; What you can do is prerender the AJAX request, so the content will be first rendered and indexed. read more about it here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/prerender

Note: it will make the page load slower. What you're going to do by that is basically stop the page from loading completely, rendering the specific requests you wish to render and only then load the content on the browser.

That's also why I must say: using AJAX on the front end for this task (related articles) is wrong. You should try getting the related articles on server side, not by AJAX requests but by a DB query - depends on your CMS.